# Clash of Clans War Placing (Teslas Question)

Tags: clash-of-clans

So I'm fully aware that the war lineup is fully based off of defense level. But I'm still stuck wondering why I'm behind a lot of players. I have maxed (for TH9) archer towers, cannons, air defenses, and half level 9 walls, the other half are level 8. The players ahead of me are basically 8.5s, with only their teslas  higher level than mine. Do teslas make up that much of how rankings are based?

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to check Base weight calculator. Sometimes trophy count and league level is counted, when 2 players have nearly same defense levels. I have experienced this many times.